# How to detect if 2d UI element is stretched?

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, scripting

A UI element can have width\height or be stretched (horisontally\vertically or bouth ways):

[image]

How to detect if a RectTransform is set to use "stretch"?

Answer (score 0):

When a `transform` is stretched to its parent, It would have following properties

```
anchorMin = (0,0);
anchorMax = (1,1);
sizeDelta = (0,0);
```

you can confirm this by changing inspector to debug mode.

Comment: What changes when it is stretched partially ?

Comment: Changing anchor preset will change anchorMax and anchorMin. Changing  left,right,top,bottom will change sizeDelta and anchoredPosition. You can learn more by playing with different configurations and switching to debug inspector to see what is changing and how its changing.